# Although I have put left=0cm in geometry package option, but there also a margin in output pdf

Tags: margins, geometry

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forloop}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[numerals=Devanagari]{bengali}
\setmainlanguage{bengali}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\bengalifont[Script=Bengali]{Akaash}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=0cm,top=0cm,bottom=0cm]{geometry}
\newcommand{\aline}{\\\hline \arabic{theyflines} &&&&&&&\rule{0cm}{0.5cm}}
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\newcounter{theyflines}
%\begin{center}
%Extension - 1
%\end{center}
\begin{tabular}{|p{0.15cm}|p{6cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.3cm}|p{1cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{4.5cm}|p{3cm}|}
\hline
{\tiny ক্রমিক} নং & নাম & রুম নং & ডিপার্টমেন্ট & বর্ষ & সেশন & মোবাইল নং & জেলা
\forloop{theyflines}{1}{\value{theyflines} < 40}{\aline}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Paragraph indentation, place `\noindent` right before `\begin{tabular} `

Comment: If you just wanted to generate a cropped image it's probably easier to just use the standalone class, it does that by default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this helps: after setting the margin with `geometry` package, use the `\noindent` (as mentioned by `@daleif`) to remove the indent spacing. That will give you `0pt` margin.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[left=0in, top=0in,bottom=0in]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{tabular}{|p{0.15cm}|p{6cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.3cm}|p{1cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{4.5cm}|p{3cm}|}
    \hline
    {\tiny a} & n & v & e & a & h& e & q\\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]